# Powershell AzureRM Module getting automatically Uninstalled on My Machine

Tags: powershell, azure

While using Powershell on my local Win 10 machine, AzureRM Module is getting automatically Uninstalled frequently somehow. I have PS 5.1 Installed.

I am not sure why this is happening.

Every time I have to go to WebPI and reinstall Azure PowerShell from there. And there it is showing me that Azure Powershell is available to be installed. Thsi is happening every few hours, even when I am not using Powershell locally at all.

Comment: If possible, I suggest you could install Azure msi from the [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases).

Comment: I already tried installing from Github too. But the same issue persists. Last change I did anywhere was to install the Posh Pro Tools from Adam Driscoll. I also removed them, but to no use.

Answer (score 0):

Is your machine configured using PowerShell DSC, I guess your machine is restoring to desired state every time after installing the modules.

Comment: Nopes. Not configured using DSC at all.